# Error when making a composite of four false color NDVIs

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, composite-key

everything needed is here except importing Landsat 8 Surface Reflectance Tier 1.

I keep getting an error when I'm making a composite of 4 different false color NDVIs and I'm not sure what it means. I am somewhat of a beginner coding in GEE. Here is the error:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
var maskL8sr = function(image) {  // adapted from GEE docs
  // Bits 3 and 5 are cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
  var cloudShadowBitMask = (1 << 3),
      cloudsBitMask = (1 << 5),
      snowBitMask = (1 << 4);
  // Get the pixel QA band.
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
               .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0))
               .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(snowBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask);
};
var addNdvi = function(image) { // adapted from GEE tutorial #6
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
};
var favoriteBands = ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'pixel_qa'];
dataset = dataset
    // .filterBounds(nj)  // this gets us paths we don't want
    .filterMetadata('WRS_PATH', 'equals', 14)
    .filterMetadata('WRS_ROW', 'equals', 32)
    .select(favoriteBands);
var 
    winterFilter = ee.Filter.dayOfYear(356, 80),
    springFilter = ee.Filter.dayOfYear(81, 172),
    summerFilter = ee.Filter.dayOfYear(173, 264),
    fallFilter = ee.Filter.dayOfYear(265, 355),
    winter = dataset.filter(winterFilter).map(addNdvi).map(maskL8sr),
    spring = dataset.filter(springFilter).map(addNdvi).map(maskL8sr),
    summer = dataset.filter(summerFilter).map(addNdvi).map(maskL8sr),
    fall = dataset.filter(fallFilter).map(addNdvi).map(maskL8sr),
    diff = summer.select('NDVI').median()
        .subtract(winter.select('NDVI').median());

// set up some cartography stuff
// https://colorbrewer2.org/#type=sequential&scheme=Purples&n=5
var seqPalette = ['f2f0f7','cbc9e2','9e9ac8','756bb1','54278f'];
var rgbVis = {
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
  min: 0,
  max: 3000,
  gamma: 1.4,
};
var colorizedVis = {
  bands: ['NDVI'],
  min: 0.0,
  max: 1.0,
  palette: [
    'FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', '74A901',
    '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01',
    '012E01', '011D01', '011301'
  ],
};
var diffVis = {
  min: -0.01,
  max: 0.46,
  palette: seqPalette,
};
states = ee.Image().byte().paint({
  featureCollection: states,
  width: 2,
});

// bake a layer cake
Map.centerObject(nj, 8);
Map.addLayer(winter, rgbVis, 'Winter RGB');
Map.addLayer(spring, rgbVis, 'Spring RGB');
Map.addLayer(summer, rgbVis, 'Summer RGB');
Map.addLayer(fall, rgbVis, 'Fall RGB');

Map.addLayer(winter, colorizedVis, 'Winter NDVI');
Map.addLayer(spring, colorizedVis, 'Spring NDVI');
Map.addLayer(summer, colorizedVis, 'Summer NDVI');
Map.addLayer(fall, colorizedVis, 'Fall NDVI');
Map.addLayer(diff, diffVis, 'Difference');
//Map.addLayer(states, {palette: ['DF0174']}, "States");

// debug
print(summer);
print(winter);
print(diff);
print(states);

// change detection RGB compositing

//Landsat 8
var vizParams1 = {
  bands: ['B5', 'B4', 'B3'],
  min: 0,
  max: 4000,
  gamma: [.9]
};

Map.setCenter(-74.0, 40.55, 8);
Map.addLayer(winter, vizParams1, 'T1 false color');
Map.addLayer(spring, vizParams1, 'T2 false color');
Map.addLayer(summer, vizParams1, 'T3 false color');
Map.addLayer(fall, vizParams1, 'T4 false color');
//concatenate 4 layers into a single image
var composite = ee.Image.cat([
  winter.select('B5'), spring.select('B5'), summer.select('B5'), fall.select('B5')]);
var vizParams2 = {
  bands: ['B5_2', 'B5_1', 'B5'],
  min: 0,
  max: 4000,
  gamma: [.9]
};
Map.addLayer(composite, vizParams2, 'T1-T2-T3-T4 NIR composite');
```

Comment: Perhaps you are missing some code in your example, but I cannot see what satellite imagery you are using.  Just "dataset".

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide code which is complete enough to _run_ and let anyone reproduce the problem.

Comment: Im using Landsat 8 Surface Reflectance. image collection